# How to join two thin wires so that they can withstand physical stress?

Tags: wire

I'm trying to join two rather thin wires (headphones cable in this particular case) that will later be worn by a human and therefore subject to quite a bit of physical stress (bending, pulling). Obviously I'd like my joint to withstand this. I do intend to solder the ends together (I don't think that I have any alternative anyway), but I don't think that will be enough.

The first idea is to wrap it with insulation tape, but previous experiences tell me that it won't help. The adhesive just isn't strong enough and the cable ends will be pulled apart, rather sooner than later.

What other options do I have?

Comment: (`I don't think that I have any alternative [to soldering]` Why dismiss crimping? IDC may easily get too much of a bulk)

Comment: @greybeard - In general, yes. But the wires inside a headphone cable are insulated with a thin layer of lacquer. Crimping them would result in no contact, I think. I need to burn away the lacquer anyway, so I might as well go the last step and just solder them together directly.

Comment: @Vilx-:  You might want to take a look at  [this guide to soldering headset wires.](https://josepheoff.github.io/posts/howtosolder-17-headset)  I wrote it up while I was doing [some experiments with Android headsets.](https://josepheoff.github.io/posts/androidtranscribe4)  I recently soldered about 40 joints using headphone wire to replace a broken flat flex connector using the methods described in the soldering guide.

Comment: @JRE - Nice! In my case the break is in the middle of the cable (I'm removing a broken microphone to leave just the headphones), but much of the advice still applies. Tell me - do you think a heat shrink tube would stick well enough to the insulation to prevent the ends being pulled apart?

Comment: Nope.  Heat shrink tubing is insulation.  It doesn't do anything at all for being pulled on.  I used to work on headsets for professional two-way radios (police walkie-talkies.)  Where we had to splice a cable, we'd use a little plastic box.  The junction was inside the box, and there were clips crimped on to the headset cables to provide strain relief.  The clips were fixed to the inside of the junction box so they didn't move.  Crimping the clips of the cable spread the load over all of the wires and the exterior insulation.  You had all the wires and the insulation carrying the load.

Comment: @Vilx- Would it be too difficult to replace the entire cable?

Comment: The simplest way would be to tie the two cables in a knot, then solder (and insulate) the individual wires.  It'd be ugly, but it would hold up pretty well.  Outside of that, find a small cylindrical plastic box (tube with both ends closed.)  Drill holes in the ends, pass the cables through, tie knots, solder the wires, stuff it all inside the tube so that it looks neater.

Comment: Check out the Android headset post to see how to do strain relief with knots.

Comment: @JRE - Hmm, that requires a box. OTOH, the microphone is already a small box. Maybe I  can work with that...

Comment: @AndrewMorton - Also a fair idea. Perhaps that is what I should do. I just need to find a replacement cable.

Comment: @Vilx- You could find a headphone extension lead and cut off the end you don't need so you only have half the hassle of soldering that wire. OTOH, it might be difficult to get into the headphones to solder that end. But at least there wouldn't be an annoying lump in the middle.

Answer (score 1):

You could;

1. Add mechanical support, for example by adding heat shrink over the solder connection.
2. Add strain relief, for example tying a knot in the cable, with the solder connection in the middle, so that when the wire is pulled it pulls on the knot and not on the solder connection.
3. Add a braided sleeve which absorbs the stresses: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QsVE1.jpg

Comment: Hmm, how would a braided sleeve work? I think they are generally pretty loose.

Comment: I've little experience with heat shrinks. Do they stick well enough to the wire insulation that they could prevent the ends from being pulled apart?

Comment: Adhesive lined heat shrink may offer better support